# Run stored procedure for each val in array

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, loops, foreach

Can't wrap my head around this one..

I have two separate stored procedures, let's call them:

```
createTable (takes a varchar userID as input)
runReport (takes two dates for input, as varchar)
```

createTable creates a virtual table called ##tempTable (if it doesn't exists and add the provided userID). So if I run

```
EXEC createTable 'user-32'
EXEC createTable 'user-33'
EXEC createTable 'user-34'
```

I then have these IDs in ##tempTable.

After that I want to run this:

```
 EXEC runReport '2011-01-01', '2011-10-01'
```

Which should give me a big tasty output.
The thing is that this works flawlessly when running it like so:

```
 mssql_query("EXEC createTable 'user-32'");
 mssql_query("EXEC createTable 'user-33'");
 mssql_query("EXEC createTable 'user-34'");
 mssql_query("EXEC runReport '2011-01-01', '2011-10-01'");
```

But when I try to loop out the createTable-lines the runReport-SP doesn't return any data.

Example:

```
$userIDs = explode(',', $userID_str);
foreach ($userIDs as $user) {
  if (mb_strlen($user) > 0) {
    mssql_query("EXEC createTable '$user'");
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if this could have anything to do with a broken connection or something? It seems that the runReport-SP can find the #tempTable but it can't read from it when I use a loop.

Any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Comment: How does `$userID_str` look like?

Comment: It's just a string, like so: user-31,user-32,user-33

Comment: And are U sure that `mb_strlen($user) > 0` will evaluate as TRUE?

Comment: Hmm, and do U get any error? Some warnings? Make sure U have this on the beginning of the script (or at Your index, init or config.php): `ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Also try to var_dump the mssql_query() return value whether it is not returning a FALSE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about calling Your procedures this way:

```
$conn = mssql_connect(...);
$stmt = mssql_init("createTable", $conn);
foreach ($userIDs as $user) {
    if(mb_strlen($user) > 0) {
        mssql_bind($stmt, "@userID", &$user, SQLVARCHAR);
        mssql_execute($stmt);
    }
}

$stmt = mssql_init("runReport", $conn);
mssql_bind($stmt, "@date1", "2011-01-01", SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($stmt, "@date2", "2011-01-01", SQLVARCHAR);
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);
print_r(mssql_fetch_array($result));
```

?